# Fortran PARAMETER variable initialized from input

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, is the `PARAMETER` attribute set at runtime or compilation time?
I was wondering if I can pass in the size the of the array at run time and have this set as `PARAMETER`.

Can this be done? If so, how? If not, why?

Comment: I've no idea of a much better title, but note that something with the `parameter` attribute is anything but a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need dynamic allocation if the size of your array is to be defined as runtime. All parameter (constants) must be defined as compiling time.

Comment: @kirikoumath, I am glad to help. Remember to accept the answer so that people who have the same problem can find it easily. If you have another question, just ask.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as repeatedly answered, a named constant (an object with the `parameter` attribute) must have its initial value "known at compile time".  However, as you talk about the size of arrays I'll note something else.

When declaring the shape of an array there are many times when the bounds needn't be given by constant expressions (of which a simple named constant is one example).  So, in the main program or a module

```
implicit none
...
integer, dimension(n) :: array  ! Not allowed unless n is a named constant.
end program
```

the `n` must be a constant.  In many other contexts, though, `n` need only be a specification expression.

```
implicit none
integer n

read(*,*) n
block
  ! n is valid specification expression in the block construct
  integer, dimension(n) :: array1
  call hello(n)
end block

contains

  subroutine hello(n)
    integer, intent(in) :: n  ! Again, n is a specification expression.
    integer, dimension(2*n) :: array2
  end subroutine

end program
```

That is, `array1` and `array2` are explicit shape *automatic objects*.  For many purposes one doesn't really need a named constant.

Beyond the array size, the following is certainly not allowed, though.

```
implicit none
integer n, m

read(*,*) n, m
block
  ! n and m are specifications expression in the block construct
  integer(kind=m), dimension(n) :: array  ! But the kind needs a constant expression.
  ...
end block
```

Answer (score 3):

The value of a `parameter` is set at compile time.

A declaration such as

```
integer, parameter :: number_of_widgets = numwidge
```

requires that `numwidge` be known at compile time, indeed known before it is encountered on the *rhs* of the declaration.

Comment: so can I do something like this:
   
    `INTEGER, PARAMETER (n = variable)`

where `variable` is a value read from an input file?

Comment: @kirikoumath Only if `variable` is a constant as well.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt How can I define a constant variable thats read from an input file?

Comment: @You can't. (At least at runtime). However, you could use a pre-processor to define `variable`.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I miss the `config const` and `config param` from chapel.